# Backbone.js results of fetch doubling

Tags: django, backbone.js, tastypie

I am trying to use Django and tastypie with backbone.js and mustache. I have set up an example to study those. When using the below code I get results of users doubling as:

- -Id  User name
- -1   yol
- -2   dada
- -1   yol
- -2   dada

--- MY CODE ---

```js
// I think this tastypie adjustment is not related with the problem but i want you to see the //whole code

window.TastypieModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        base_url: function() {
          var temp_url = Backbone.Model.prototype.url.call(this);
          return (temp_url.charAt(temp_url.length - 1) == '/' ? temp_url : temp_url+'/');
        },

        url: function() {
          return this.base_url();
        }
    });

    window.TastypieCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        parse: function(response) {
            this.recent_meta = response.meta || {};
            return response.objects || response;
        }
});


(function($){



// MODELS-COLLECTIOS
  //USERS
  var User = TastypieModel.extend({
      url: USERS_API
  });

  var Users = TastypieCollection.extend({
      model: User,
      url:USERS_API
  });



//VIEWS
  var UsersView = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function(){
         // template with ICanHaz.js (ich)
        this.el = ich.userRowTpl(this.model.toJSON());
        return this;
       }
  });





//main app
  var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
      tagName: 'tbody',
      initialize: function() {
          this.users = new Users();
          this.users.bind('all', this.render, this);
          this.users.fetch();
      },

      render: function () {

          // template with ICanHaz.js (ich)
          this.users.each(function (user) {
             $(this.el).append(new UsersView({model: user}).render().el);
          }, this);



          return this;
      }
  });

  var app = new AppView();
  $('#app').append(app.render().el);






})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say you are firing two times the render, because your view is listening to all events, try instead to bind it just to reset and see how it goes:

```
initialize: function() {
  this.users = new Users();
  this.users.bind('reset', this.render, this);
  this.users.fetch();
},
```

Comment: Thank you. It solves doubling. But i did a little test within **AppView's render** function and wrote an `alert('test')` function.  And it calls alert two times meaning it goes into render two times is this the expected behaviour ?

Comment: Yes, because you are still calling render two times, the first `$('#app').append(app.render().el);` and the second `this.users.bind('reset', this.render, this);` which is the expected way, because in the first call the collection hasn't been fetched yet so the one that it's rendering the models of the collection is the one bound to the reset event, fired after the collection it's fetched.